# Is it possible to cause multi processes hibernate (core dump?)?

Tags: c++, coredump

I have a software (c++) that runs few processes (each process is a major system itself).

The processes have communication with each other via xml-rpc or boost asio

I want to be able to freeze or stop all processes at a given moment and be able to raise the system (all processes) later to the same state as before hibernating.

How can I do that in c++?

Would it be feasible due to the fact that the processes communicates with each other?

Comment: It may be easier to run all in a shared VM, and hibernate the entire VM.

Answer (score 2):

The big picture is that you need to get the system to a stable consistent state, then persist that state in some re-creatable form.

You can in principle write such code, the degree of difficulty depends on your application. You will need to figure out things such as:

- How the processes agree that they are in a consistent state. You may need to define some new "Get ready to hibernate" and "I'm ready" messages.
- For each process you need to figure out how to persist and recover it's state. Depending upon the complexity of any live data structures that may be quite tricky. On the other hand, if your processes are stateless then this could be really easy.
- You'll need to devise a scheme for managing the sets of hibernated data, how you determine a consistent set across all the processes.

I see this as significant coding effort, the degree of difficulty will depend on the complexity of your application and the quality of its implementation. In a well structured application such major "replumbing" exercises often go surprisingly simply.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're an OS - no, it won't be possible.

What you need to do instead is to make sure that each process can do it for itself (i.e.: **write** a functionality that allows saving and restoring the states for each of the processes), and also to accommodate for inconsistencies in the communication (for example - to ensure ACK on the messages, and resend if saved state without receiving ACK).

It's feasible if done right, but it's easier said than done, of course, and assumes you can actually change the processes.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

the other answers are fine. There is another rather "exotic" way which may solve this quickly, but it may be overkill or not suitable. But who knows ? So just in case...

I suggest to run your program into a virtual machine (I mean for example a linux with vmware) and pause/wake up this virtual machine at will.

If you are using an inter-process communication method which is not disrupted by this kind of operation, it may work and save you a lot of time.

Good luck.